# HTTP Status 403 While Implementing Declarative Security

Tags: tomcat, struts2, security

I did the following changes to implement declarative security in tomcat(in a struts2 application)

I added the following in tomcat-users.xml

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="Manager"/>
  <user username="manager1" password ="password1" roles="Manager"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

In my web.xml I made the following changes

```xml
<security-role>
  <role-name>Manager</role-name>
</security-role>
<login-config>
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>  

<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>     
    <web-resource-name>MANAGER Access</web-resource-name>    
    <url-pattern>/manager/*</url-pattern>   
    <http-method>DELETE</http-method>    
    <http-method>PUT</http-method>    
    <http-method>HEAD</http-method>   
    <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>   
    <http-method>TRACE</http-method>     
    <http-method>GET</http-method>    
    <http-method>POST</http-method>  
  </web-resource-collection>  

  <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>Manager</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

when I access the URL appcontextname/manager/something.action , it prompts for a username and password, after I provide the details it gives me the following error

HTTP Status 403 - Access to the requested resource has been denied